# Core data and version control

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Core Data model that will be getting two new model versions in two separate branches.

- Will merging the two branches work properly (`xcdatamodel` seems to be an XML file)? That is, will it create the two new versions?
- What about versioning after merge: how would I create a new model version that contains the changes from both versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the merging of Core Data Models a real pain and have decided to avoid it at all costs.

Versioned data models are actually directory containing model files for each version. Since for automatic lightweight version Core Data needs to work through all version files in sequence, it keeps some kind of hash string about base version among its current version. Which basically means that when two different developers start a new version from the same base version, you are screwed when you try to merge those. You may even get it to work on clean device, but will likely fail if you want to migrate data from prior version.